# Table layout panel - Anchoring in C# form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two table layout panels in my c# form application. One I created through the design tools (TableLayoutPanel1). The second one is dynamically created (TableLayoutPanel2). The first table layout actually contains the headings for the second table. So I want to align them properly.

I applied all the same properties of TableLayoutPanel1 to TableLayoutPanel2. But still, they are not aligned. TableLayoutPanel2 covers only half of the screen but TableLayoutPanel1 covers the entire screen.

```
TableLayoutPanel TableLayoutPanel2 = new TableLayoutPanel();
TableLayoutPanel2 .Size = new Size (1173,35);  //same size as 1
TableLayoutPanel2 .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;  //left and right anchor

TableLayoutPanel2 .Location = new Point(5, 60);
TableLayoutPanel2 .RowCount = 1;
TableLayoutPanel2 .ColumnCount = 2;
TableLayoutPanel2 .ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
TableLayoutPanel2 .ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
```

What is the problem here? Any suggestions.

Comment: Where/when are you creating this new TLP? Have you tried setting `TableLayoutPanel2 .Size = tableLayoutPanel1.Size;`? Is your app DpiAware? Yu can also add them both to a FlowLayoutPanel and anchor both inside this outer container. Also, when you create a TLP in code, clear the existing styles before adding your own.

Comment: I create this on a menu click event.

Comment: TableLayoutPanel2 .Size = tableLayoutPanel1.Size;  this worked . thanks